# Using third party JavaFX libraries in OSGi enviroment

Tags: java, maven, javafx, osgi-bundle

I have problems with using third party javafx components with my efxclipse rcp application.

For example ControlsFX. First I used [p2-maven-plugin from reficio](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin9RtkEmzsOg). Application fails because ControlsFx imports com.sun.* packages not published by EFX. I have tried to add these internal packages to my setup through [sistem bundle fragment](https://gist.github.com/rotty3000/1291842). Failed again. Then I have tried to bundle all dependencies of component (all jars) to one bundle (with extracted classes and without them / just jars). This method works but breaks css skins of components. So any css and skin operation like caret or icons missed.

I have tried libraries like RichTextFX, ControlsFX, JideFX, JFXtras ... Every time same result. All these libraries work under normal Maven JavaFX application setup. Obviously I am doing it wrong way. What is the right way??!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to transform the library to an OSGI ready bundle. This is simple just follow this: http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/21893960212/how-to-turn-a-jdbc-driver-jar-into-an-osgi-bundle
good luck :)

Comment: I know this technic. I have mentioned I have tried this way. And as I said CSS and some behavior like caret positioning, scrolls do not work.